# Section com display block não funciona corretamente

Tags: html5, css3

Estou com o seguinte problema: Abri um tópico ontem referente a umas posições que estavam ficando erradas, e que consegui resolver. Porém, apareceu outro problema que consiste no seguinte: Nesta imagem está o efeito que eu procuro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aqui está o efeito que consegui com o meu código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até ai tudo certo, porém, vejam o que acontece quando redimensiono a tela do site :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebam que na tela desse site as suas `<section>` ficam uma em baixo da outra, com uma fina borda separando as duas, e nas bordas laterais não tem, ficando exatamente zeradas.

Agora essa é a minha tela redimensionada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebam que a minha `<section>` quem vem depois do `<header>` já toma uma distancia que não poderia, além de apresentar uma borda do lado esquerdo e estar meio torta. Bom, segue meu código para melhor entendimento:

```css
#sessao-1 {
  margin-top: 210px;
}
#img-info {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#img-info li {
  width: 33.333%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.img-1 {
  background-image: url(http://www.kkuodesign.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/assassins-creed-game-widescreen-wallpaper.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 59.42%;
  border-right: 7px solid #000;
}
.img-2 {
  background-image: url(http://www.1stwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/the_last_of_us_video_games_hd_wallpapers-500x300.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 59.42%;
}
.img-3 {
  background-image: url(http://www.1stwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Images-bakground-gaming-wallpaper-mortal-kombat-high-quality-hd-wallpapers-500x300.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 59.42%;
  border-left: 7px solid #000;
}
.text {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.text h1 {
  font-family: 'Trade Winds', cursive;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
}
.text p {
  width: 350px;
  max-width: 95%;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: .9em;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 20px;
}
@media(max-width: 800px) {
  #img-info li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
  }
  .text p {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="sessao-1">
  <ul id="img-info">
    <li>
      <div class="img-1">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="img-2">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="img-3">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Obs: conforme vou diminuindo a tela as minha letras começam a ser sobrepostas pelo meu background-color. Tenho quase certeza que a forma como fiz a minha `section` está errada.

Comment: Você está usando bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

Segue abaixo seu código modificado e funcionando. Só fiz algumas modificações, vou listá-las abaixo e explicar:

- Ao invés de usar `border` usei `margin` e deixei o `background` do pai preto.
- Ao adicionar as margens usei o seletor `#img-info li + li` que seleciona o próximo irmão do `li`, fazendo com que o primeiro fique sem margem.
- O `width` dos `li` foram reduzidos conforme o valor da margem aplicada.
- Coloquei `display:table` na `sessao-1`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#sessao-1 {
  margin-top: 210px;
}
#img-info {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
#img-info li {
  width: 32.666666666666666666666666666667%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#img-info li + li {
  margin-left: 1%;
}
.img-1 {
  background-image: url(http://www.kkuodesign.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/assassins-creed-game-widescreen-wallpaper.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 59.42%;
}
.img-2 {
  background-image: url(http://www.1stwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/the_last_of_us_video_games_hd_wallpapers-500x300.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 59.42%;
}
.img-3 {
  background-image: url(http://www.1stwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Images-bakground-gaming-wallpaper-mortal-kombat-high-quality-hd-wallpapers-500x300.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 59.42%;
}
.text {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.text h1 {
  font-family: 'Trade Winds', cursive;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
}
.text p {
  width: 350px;
  max-width: 95%;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: .9em;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 20px;
}
@media(max-width: 800px) {
  #img-info li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
  }
  #img-info li + li {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .text p {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="sessao-1">
  <ul id="img-info">
    <li>
      <div class="img-1">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="img-2">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="img-3">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```